# Use of Run-Time polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++

What is use of Run-Time Polymorphism in C++?

Eg:

```
Class A
{
    Virtual void Add(){-------};
}

Class B: public Class A
{
    void Add(){--------};
}

A* Ptr1;
B *Ptr2;
B ObjB;

A = &ObjB;
```

To call Add() of class B, we use A->Add()
why?

We can use

```
B = &ObjB;
B->Add()
```

or

```
ObjB.Add();
```

What is the use of Run Time polymorphism??
Even we can directly call the Class B's Add() method by its object or by its pointer.Then why we don't do so and we choose a complicated way instead of simple way?

Comment: I think you missed the concept of polymorphism. Imagine having two classes deriving from `A`, and try putting it into a collection, then call `Add` on every object of this collection.

Comment: The question really seems to be "Why do we use polymorphism?"

Comment: @Luk/Joseph: B has  some "is-a" relationship with  A, that's why A is made as base class of B. B is inherited from A and B has all the inherited features of A. But still why do we need the calling procedure of B's Add() in this way.even we can call it directly by its object or its own pointer.then why use of pointer A for this?

Comment: @user2935896 _"We would have some "is-a" relationship"_ Yes, and?

Comment: You don't *need* to call the function through the `A` pointer in your example. The point is that even if all you have is an `A` pointer (i.e. the calling code has no clue whatsoever that it actually points to a `B`) it will call `B`'s function.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of Run Time polymorphism??

The use is to define a common base class (often one that only defines an abstract interface), that allows code to interact with any class derived from that base, without knowing or caring about the exact type. So you can write a function `furtle(A&)` which works with `A`, `B` or any other class derived from `A`. It can call the virtual functions, which are overridden to do the right thing whatever the actual class type is.

> Even we can directly call the Class B's Add() method by its object or by its pointer. Then why we don't do so and we choose a complicated way instead of simple way?

If you're only going to interact directly with a single class, then you're right; there's no point making it polymorphic. You'd only do it if you want to write more generic code that works with more types than just `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot: 
luk32 ,Joseph,Mansfield ,molbdnilo ,Mike Seymour